# Links to scientific articles in Q/A/C

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

How can we choose links to scientific articles in questions (Q), answers (A), and comments (C)?

---

On some Stack Exchange sites, e.g., involved in science, it's indispensable to link to scientific articles in Q/A/C. Explaining the linked material instead of referring to it is often not an option: too much work, too much space used (esp. in comment).

That causes two related issues:

- Link rot: links tend to become dead sooner or later, and while it's often possible to find an alternative link, it takes a lot of work (for moderators or helpful contributors) to edit Q/A/C. And for Q/A, that needlessly brings the material in active questions (at least on some sites). In the case of C, the substitution might be impossible if the new link is longer, and it requires a moderator or SE staff anyway.
- Choice between links with differing convenience and legality, as illustrated below.

Motivating example: on *[Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour)* where I'm a moderator, it's often made reference to R.L. Rivest, A. Shamir, and L. Adleman, *A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems*, in Communications of the ACM, Feb. 1978, Volume 21, Issue 2, pp 120–126. We can use as link

1. The DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/359340.359342
2. What the DOI redirects to: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/359340.359342
3. The article in 2: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359340.359342 (it's a PDF and happens to not be paywalled at time of writing).
4. An author's page with reference to the article: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs.html#RSA78. That option is rarely available, especially with the possibility to directly link to the correct part of the page, and links equivalents to 1/2/3/4!
5. A re-typeset version which happens to be available: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf (here: it's on an author's website, thus presumably authorized, plus there's legalese on the bottom of the first page suggesting that). This source has been most used on *Cryptography*, and when the link became dead, the options below became attractive replacements. Fortunately the author was kind enough to put the document back online at the same URL.
6. Same as 5 from another source https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/COURSES/MAT302-S12/Rsapaper.pdf (here: on the same website, but not so obviously authorized).
7. Same as 5 from the web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230318112554/https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf, or perhaps other sources of (even?) more questionable legality.
8. A web redirection through a subdomain: https://rsa.grieu.fr, which then conveniently allows the domain owner (here, me) to decide among 1..7, or something else, without having to edit the Q/A/C. However, that begs the question of how others than me would know the URL, and gives me (or whoever may administer the domain) too much power/responsibility. So I think it can't be adequate beside perhaps my own Q/A/C.
9. Some more general long-lived URL shortener/redirector with after-the-fact edit capability, but then which, and who's granted the right to edit?
10. Some new mechanism to be built into the Stack Exchange websites.

And then there is the related issue of if we can link to material (assuming that it would be unobjectionable to link directly to an authorized document)

- only when the material linked to is explicitly OK from a copyright standpoint
- when as above or it's presumably OK (e.g., is linked to or published by an author)
- when as above and all official sources are paywalled
- only when there isn't any smoking gun that it's an unauthorized copy
- no matter what (e.g., links through Sci-Hub, LibGen, Z-Lib, Anna’s Archive are game).

Comment: Another possibility for link repository is [CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/),  To use your example, cf. [A method for obtaining digital signatures and public-key cryptosystems](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/1ff107c3230c51ae3cc8e0f14dced3eaebea9a8e), which is but one of several copies returned from searching there.  CiteSeerX did a site reorganization about a year ago, which [broke a number of links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421/), so there's always an underlying link rot risk whatever the approach.

Comment: @hardmath: my experience linking to CiteSeer(X) is bad. Lots of article have disappeared at some point, I believe for copyright reasons. And when right now I click in the send link in your comment, I get an animated progress bar of the kind that's purely visual rather than reflecting actual work being done, and nothing beyond website info in the bottom. Starting afresh from https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/ and making a search works no better.

Answer (score 3):

I would find your ten suggestions to be in descending order of preference. I think we should discourage people from linking to material of doubtful legality although it would be hard to police that.

One thing I would add is that in Q and A and, if there is space, in C we should encourage people to include the authors and the title so that if their link goes down at least later readers can paste something into their favourite search engine and have some chance of success. If it is a multi-multi-author paper just a few of the first ones should be enough. That also helps people recognise that they already have the paper so they do not have to click on the link and download it redundantly.

Comment: This answer's point of view is: legality first, which I understand. However that's leaving out of the balance that getting immediate access to a readable document is of so much value to the audience. And I can't see much drawback to 5 (better layout, reasonable evidence of being authorized) beyond the increased risk of link rot compared to 1, which 8/9/10 attempt to fix.

Comment: I prefer a link to be not directly to a pdf but to a page that contains the pdf. Such pdf's can be big and it prevents people from downloading stuff that they don't need. If a pdf is around, then it is easily found with a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend using [PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) for citing scientific articles related to biology, chemistry, medicine, etc. It is a stable repository of abstracts and full-text articles (when available). A typical citation would look like this:

*Shtatland T, Guettler D, Kossodo M, Pivovarov M, Weissleder R. PepBank--a database of peptides based on sequence text mining and public peptide data sources. BMC Bioinformatics. 2007 Aug 1;8:280. doi: 10.1186/1471-2105-8-280. PMID: 17678535; PMCID: PMC1976427. [(abstract)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17678535/) [(full text)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1976427/)*

The full text (often free, otherwise behind the paywall) is avilable by clicking the corresponding link(s) to the right of the title on PubMed.

[image: PubMed full text and citation links and buttons]

The text of the citation can be easily copied and pasted by clicking on <kbd>Cite</kbd> button to the right of the title on PubMed, then <kbd>Copy</kbd> in the pop-up window.

[image: Cite and Copy buttons]

I recommend ranking this in the preferred order as #3, right after the DOI options in the list shown in the question.